# In Astro I try to rewrite a Preact component from function to class

Tags: reactjs, preact, astrojs

There is a demo repository [here](https://github.com/withastro/astro/tree/latest/examples/framework-preact) which shows how to use Preact with [Astro](https://astro.build/)

I'm going to show here only the relevant code snippets. In the astro page file the preact component is used as follows

```
---
...
const count = signal(0);
...
---

<Counter count={count} client:visible>
    <h1>Hello, Preact 1!</h1>
</Counter>
```

In that repo the preact is defined as follows:

```
export default function Counter({ children, count }) {
    const add = () => count.value++;
    const subtract = () => count.value--;

    return (
        <>
            <div class="counter">
                <button onClick={subtract}>-</button>
                <pre>{count}</pre>
                <button onClick={add}>+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="counter-message">{children}</div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Now, I would like to rewrite this component as a class:

```
export default class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    this.subtract = this.subtract.bind(this);
  }

  add() {
    (this.props as any).count.value++;
  }

  subtract() {
    (this.props as any).count.value--;
  }

  render({ children, count }: any) {
    return (
      <>
        <div class="counter">
          <button onClick={this.subtract}>-</button>
          <button onClick={this.add}>+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="counter-message">{children}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is, is when I click + or - nothing happens, it seems that the `signal` is not working any more. So I must be doing something fundamentally wrong (Please note that I'm a React NooP!) Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why would you turn it into a class?

Comment: Is it not common to do it with classes? On the other hand for me it doesn't really matter I think. But still, I'm very curious why the class-version doesn't work

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri it's not much of an issue with Preact as they are and will be supported in the future, but React has nearly entirely moved off classes and they already are missing some features that are only available to hooks/function components.

Answer (score 0):

Signal tracking won't work through the constructor like that. You need to switch to arrow functions and manipulating the passed-in signal directly:

```
export default class Counter extends Component {
  add = () => {
    this.props.count.value++;
  }

  subtract = () => {
    this.props.count.value--;
  }

  render({ children, count }: any) {
    return (
      <>
        <div class="counter">
          <button onClick={this.subtract}>-</button>
          <button onClick={this.add}>+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="counter-message">{children}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```